# How to create API method product info in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product, api

The code should be optimized to load the page faster

Answer (score 0):

Request Example SOAP V1

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');

// If somestuff requires api authentification,
// then get a session token
$session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');

$result = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product.info', '4');
var_dump($result);

// If you don't need the session anymore
//$client->endSession($session);
```

Request Example SOAP V2

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/v2_soap/?wsdl'); // TODO : change url
$sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey'); // TODO : change login and pwd if necessary

$result = $proxy->catalogProductInfo($sessionId, '4');
var_dump($result);
Request Example SOAP V2 (WS-I Compliance Mode)
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');

$sessionId = $proxy->login((object)array('username' => 'apiUser', 'apiKey' => 'apiKey'));

$result = $proxy->catalogProductInfo((object)array('sessionId' => $sessionId->result, 'productId' => '4'));
var_dump($result->result);
```

Response Example SOAP V1

```
array
  'product_id' => string '4' (length=1)
  'sku' => string 'canon_powershot' (length=15)
  'set' => string '4' (length=1)
  'type' => string 'simple' (length=6)
  'categories' =>
    array
      0 => string '3' (length=1)
      1 => string '5' (length=1)
  'websites' =>
    array
      0 => string '2' (length=1)
  'type_id' => string 'simple' (length=6)
  'name' => string 'Canon PowerShot A630 8MP Digital Camera with 4x Optical Zoom' (length=60)
  'description' => string 'Replacing the highly popular PowerShot A620, the PowerShot A630 features a rotating 2.5-inch vari-angle LCD, 4x optical zoom lens, and a vast array of creative shooting modes.

The PowerShot A630 packs a vast array of advanced features into a remarkably compact space' (length=267)
  'short_description' => string 'Replacing the highly popular PowerShot A620, the PowerShot A630 features a rotating 2.5-inch vari-angle LCD, 4x optical zoom lens, and a vast array of creative shooting modes.' (length=175)
  'weight' => string '1.0000' (length=6)
  'old_id' => null
  'news_from_date' => null
  'news_to_date' => null
  'status' => string '1' (length=1)
  'url_key' => string 'canon-powershot-a630-8mp-digital-camera-with-4x-optical-zoom' (length=60)
  'url_path' => string 'canon-powershot-a630-8mp-digital-camera-with-4x-optical-zoom.html' (length=65)
  'visibility' => string '4' (length=1)
  'category_ids' =>
    array
      0 => string '3' (length=1)
      1 => string '5' (length=1)
  'required_options' => string '0' (length=1)
  'has_options' => string '0' (length=1)
  'image_label' => null
  'small_image_label' => null
  'thumbnail_label' => null
  'created_at' => string '2012-03-29 12:47:56' (length=19)
  'updated_at' => string '2012-03-29 12:47:56' (length=19)
  'country_of_manufacture' => null
  'price' => string '329.9900' (length=8)
  'group_price' =>
    array
      empty
  'special_price' => null
  'special_from_date' => null
  'special_to_date' => null
  'tier_price' =>
    array
      empty
  'minimal_price' => null
  'msrp_enabled' => string '2' (length=1)
  'msrp_display_actual_price_type' => string '4' (length=1)
  'msrp' => null
  'enable_googlecheckout' => string '1' (length=1)
  'tax_class_id' => string '2' (length=1)
  'meta_title' => null
  'meta_keyword' => null
  'meta_description' => null
  'is_recurring' => string '0' (length=1)
  'recurring_profile' => null
  'custom_design' => null
  'custom_design_from' => null
  'custom_design_to' => null
  'custom_layout_update' => null
  'page_layout' => null
  'options_container' => string 'container2' (length=10)
  'gift_message_available' => null
```

Reference: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.info.html